# python Windows "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." When loading compiled extension

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x, mingw-w64

I compiled a module for python using MinGW64 and it won't load.

I tried checking the file types of the files (with the mingw `file` command) and they are both 64 bit, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to add the MinGW64 lib path to the PATH.

```
> set PATH=%PATH%;%MINGW64_ROOT%\x86_64-4.9.0-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev2\mingw64\bin
```

(Also, to get this to build, I had to define the macro: `MS_WIN64`).